# Displaying Data in form after using activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that the user is going to interact with, by updating, etc.  The data is being pulled from the database, so that the user can see previous data and add new ones as well.  So basically when I try to execute the code below, I get an error, saying that there is no method...

```
@display = Sales.find(:all, :conditions => ['year =?', _year])
render :partial => "display" #which renders the table that has the form in it.

<td><%= text_field 'display', 'price'%></td> #is the input field
```

I have price as a column in my database :S

Thanks for the help guys! Merry X-mas

Comment: Is this code in three separate files? It looks like you have controller code and at least two different views here. It would be helpful to know that.

Also, seeing the exact details of the error message would be helpful for diagnosing exactly what is going on here.

Comment: the first two are in the controller, the last one is in the view _display.  Basically, what the app is doing is, asking the user for a year in the first view, edit then passes that year to the controller using observe_field and updates the view _display

Comment: undefined method `price' for #<Array:0x4923ea8>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display variable is an Array. You'll need to pass the results of the Sales.find in the :collection parameter of render partial:

```
@display = Sales.find(:all, :conditions => ['year =?', _year])
render :partial => "display", :collection => @display
```

That should render the partial once for each item that is returned by Sales.find

Comment: sorry, I should be a bit more descriptive, it still gives the same error, by which I mean, it says that its an undefined method ... :S

Comment: Is is still reporting that the display object is an Array? If so, I would change the name up a bit; that could be confusing Rails. Everything is named display, and that could be a problem.

Try:
found_sales = Sales.find(:all, :conditions => ['year =?', _year])
render :partial => "display", :collection => found_sales

Comment: Hrm, still doesnt work, sigh.  Is there any possible way I can see the array within the view

Comment: You can always loop over the elements in the array in your view with each.

Comment: I'm only adding 4 values to a table, and that's it.  The thing is, I have to be able to update the form after the user has edited the form